# How to edit a component from another library in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests

I am practicing some tests on my React app, the app is listing all user info on cards.

I want to add a custom html attribute called "data-selector-id" to a card title "h3" inside the "Card" component imported from another React library.

May I have your suggestions on how to do that?
Many thanks.

Comment: You can use `document.queryselector` inside a `useEffect` and select the desired element, then add attribute to it.